# 2D kernel density e. in python - x axis crowded and shrinked

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, kernel-density, probability-density

I have a `x,y` distribution of points for which I obtain the KDE through `scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.`

Both `kms` and `mins` are a list with float values representing the time needed to cover the amount of kilometres.

The values are distributed between:

- `mins`: [3.48996296296 - 317.678638298]
- `kms`: [0.180707205317 - 8086.94362983]

In the result I will get a high and narrow line -- the y values are shown normally, but the x-axis is very narrow and shrunken (the ticks are overlapping). Can somebody point out how the x axis can be more stretched?

Here is my code to generate the plot:

```
xmin = min(mins)
xmax = max(mins)
ymin = min(kms)
ymax = max(kms)

X, Y = np.mgrid[xmin:xmax:1000j, ymin:ymax:100j]
positions = np.vstack([X.ravel(), Y.ravel()])
values = np.vstack([mins, kms])
kernel = stats.gaussian_kde(values)
Z = np.reshape(kernel(positions).T, X.shape)

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax.imshow(np.rot90(Z), cmap=plt.cm.gist_earth_r, extent=[xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax])
ax.plot(mins, kms, 'k.', markersize=2)
ax.set_xlim([xmin, 200])
ax.set_ylim([ymin, ymax])

plt.show()
```

And here is the plot itself:

[image]

Comment: If you can provide a link to your picture, I can edit it to your question for you.

Comment: many thanks, you saved me a great deal of explanation this way. :)
[link](http://tinyurl.com/jwetoew)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the aspect ratio of the plot from 1:1 to automatic via

`ax.axis('normal')`